# How to reformat columns in feature file in intelliJ for MAC

Tags: intellij-idea, gherkin, feature-file

I have a feature file in IntelliJ but don't know how to reformat the columns. Tried a couple of options but none of them are working

I have tried Ctrl + Alt + L, Ctrl + shft+ Alt + L

```
Then the "abc"  box should show the following options
      | Value         | i18n                    | status | Number |
      | abc           | [儲abcД]                 | true    |       |
      | xyz           | [儲굻ßxyzДß]             | true    | 3     |
      | pqr           | [儲굻ßДpqrДß굻]           | true    | 1     |
      | def           | [儲굻ßdefДß굻]            | true    | 1     |
```

Expected: These columns should be aligned.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should enable/install Gherkin plugin, Settings -> Plugins. This plugin should enable syntax highlighting and formatting.

Comment: I found the solution for this because there are some special characters involved that's why none of the shortcuts and settings are working here.